# in github pages how to undo theme-chooser

Tags: css, jekyll, html, github-pages

I chose a built-in github page theme earlier for a github.io page but eventually decided to use my own html/css file. However as a webdev beginner I couldn't find a way to un-do the theme, even after removing the .yml file. Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Jekyll themes are configured in `_config.yml`.

Open `_config.yml`, remove `theme: minima` or the theme you have selected, and build your own structure.

Answer (score 0):

> To unpublish your Project Pages site, delete the gh-pages or master branch

Seems like there should be a way to unpublish without deleting **master**, but hey ho

https://help.github.com/articles/unpublishing-a-project-pages-site/